# What does the exclamation mark stands for on Vue Property Decorator

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I am getting familiar with the use of typescript in vue.
When reading the documentation of vue property decorator I cannot get what this declaration stands for

```
@Prop({ default: 'default value' }) readonly propB!: string
```

Answer (score 12):

In this specific case, the bang operator is used because you know that your property `propB` cannot be `null` or `undefined` as the decorator takes care of filling in a value. TypeScript does not know this and since you are not assigning a value directly or in the constructor, it expects the type signature to be `string | undefined`. The exlamation mark tells TypeScript that you know the value will never be `undefined` and reduces the signature to `string` only without complaining about the possibility of it being `undefined`.

You only need this if you set the TypeScript compiler option to `strict` (this is strongly encouraged!).